# git branch name auto-completion

Tags: git, branch

I am aware the title may not be descriptive enough but I could not think of a name for my problem. I hope I will be more clear with my issue in the body.

Let's assume I have two branches:

1. feature/PROJ-100-placeholder-a
2. feature/PROJ-101-placeholder-b

When I `git checkout fea` "TAB" I would expect **git** to autocomplete up to `feature/PROJ-10` but instead it autocompletes all the way to either `feature/PROJ-100-placeholder-a` or `feature/PROJ-101-placeholder-b`

Any clues on how I can amend the current behaviour to my desired one?

I am on **MacOS**, running **git-bash** with the following config in my `.bashrc`:

```
if [ -f $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion ]; then
  . $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion
fi

if [ -f $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash ]; then
  . $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash
fi

if [ -f `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion.d/git-flow-completion.bash 
]; then
  . `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion.d/git-flow-completion.bash
fi
```

Many thanks,

Emanuell

Comment: I have the expected behavior you describe running git-bash on Windows 10. Can you edit into your question what shell/command line and OS you're using?

Comment: I found an answer to this same question on Apple Stack Exchange here - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/392382/105557 - the main thing is to use this command for homebrew - ```brew install zsh-completion```

Answer (score 0):

See [appendix A1.7 of the Git handbook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Appendix-A%3A-Git-in-Other-Environments-Git-in-Zsh):

> Zsh also ships with a tab-completion library for Git. To use it, simply run `autoload -Uz compinit && compinit` in your `.zshrc`.